# Passing Value In Java

Tags: java

I was given a task to create a java program that use this 3 classes. Main class, Menu class and Coffee Class. Now i need to pass value from menu class to coffee class. But the problem is i dont exactly know how to do it since im still new with java.

CoffType pass the value to CoffeeName.
NumBag pass the value to NumberOfBag.

This is menu class(programmer defined class 1)

```
 import java.util.*;
public class Menu {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public String coffType;
    public int numBag;

    public void setCoffType() {
        System.out.println("\t\tChoose Your Coffee");
        System.out.println("\n[1] Arabica\tRM12.50 per bag");
        System.out.println("\n[2] Robusta\tRM15.00 per bag");
        coffType = scan.nextLine();

    }

    public void setNumBag() {
        System.out.println("Enter amount you wish to buy");
        numBag = scan.nextInt();
    }

}
```

Coffee Class(programmer defined class 2)

```
    public class Coffee{
    private String coffeeName;
    private double coffeePrice;
    private double amountPay;
    private int numberOfBag;
    private double discount;

    public Coffee() { // constructor
        coffeeName = "unknown";
        coffeePrice = 0.00;
        amountPay = 0.00;
        numberOfBag = 0;
        discount = 0.00;
    }



    public double getCoffeePrice() {
        if(coffeeName.equalsIgnoreCase("arabica")) {
        coffeePrice = 12.50 * numberOfBag;
        }
        else if(coffeeName.equalsIgnoreCase("robusta")) {
            coffeePrice = 15.00 * numberOfBag;
        }
        System.out.println("Price RM: " +coffeePrice);
        return coffeePrice;
    }

    public double getDiscount() {
        if(numberOfBag>0 && numberOfBag<=50) {
            discount = coffeePrice*0;
        }
        if(numberOfBag>50 && numberOfBag<=100) {
            discount = coffeePrice*0.10;
        }
        if(numberOfBag>100 && numberOfBag<=150) {
            discount = coffeePrice*0.15;
        }
        if(numberOfBag>150 && numberOfBag<=200) {
            discount = coffeePrice*0.20;
        }
        if(numberOfBag>200) {
            discount = coffeePrice*0.25;
        }
        System.out.println("Discount RM: " +discount);
        return discount;
    }

    public double getAmountPay() {
        amountPay = coffeePrice - discount;
        System.out.println("\nTotal Need To Pay RM: " +amountPay);
        return amountPay;
    }


}
```

I want to pass `coffType` to `coffeeName` and `numbag` to `numberOfBag`. How can i change these values?

Comment: Please follow conventions, and start naming attributs/variables with lowercase ;)

Comment: Read up constructors, getters and setters.

Comment: Do you understand the concept of OOP? Do you understand the concepts of object and instance?

Comment: Links you should take a look: [convention](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions), [OOP](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-oops-concepts), [Encapsulation](https://www.javatpoint.com/encapsulation)

Comment: @ Kaizen mark an answer as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, inorder to pass the value of CoffType to CoffeeName and NumBag to NumberOfBag we can either use a parameterized constructor or setters. Both ways we can pass the value from Menu class to Coffee class.

1. Using parameterized constructor 
   create parameterized constructor in the Coffee class and instantiate the Coffee class from the Menu class.
2. Setter

create 2 setters to set each of NumberOfBag and CoffeName in the Coffee class and set the value by instatiating Coffee class and setting the value to both.

Answer (score 2):

In CoffeClass create a constructor that receives the parameter that you want to set:

```
public Coffee(String coffeeName, double amountPay, int numberOfBag) {
        this.coffeeName = coffeeName;
        this.amountPay = amountPay;
        this.numberOfBag = numberOfBag;
    }
```

In MenuClass you will instantiate the object Coffe with the selected values by the user:

```
Coffe coffeOne = new Coffe(coffeName, amoutPay, numBag);
```

In the same class use the object to get the discount:

```
double discountCoffeOne = coffeOne.getDiscount();
```

You're done.

You use the CoffeClas as a model to an object with the values that you want. That way you can have a lot of different coffe just instantiating another Coffe with another name and using it.

When needed you should use `getters` and `setters` to change the attributes of an object, when needed means you should not create them when the values are not supposed to change or the other classes should not have permission to change these attributes.

```
public setCoffeeName(String coffeeName){
  this.coffeeName = coffeName
};

public getCoffeeName(){
  return coffeName;
}
```

;)

Oh, and just like azro said:

"Please follow conventions, and start naming attributs/variables with lowercase"